# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, but I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)`

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");
$result = mysqli_query($con , "select * from members where id=$id");

echo <<<_END;
<form action = "updatemem.php" method = 'POST'>
<br><br><br><br>

<center>

<b>EDIT RECORD</b><br><br>

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>";
echo "Lastname: <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$row[lastname]'><br/>";
echo "Codename: <input type='password' name='codename' value='$row[codename]'><br/>";
echo "Location: <input type='text' name='location' value='$row[location]'><br/>";
echo "Rank: <input type='text' name='rank' value='$row[rank]'><br/>";
}


<br>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Record">
</center>
</form>
?>
```

the error is on line 7 which is `echo <<<_END;` . I already tried `echo<<END;` and checking on whitespaces as what the other users commented on other thread having this same error. What are/is the possible solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)

Look at the error. It says it is getting an parsing & syntax error around code that has `<<`. So look in your code and find that `<<` item. So then what exactly is `echo <<<_END;`? Some are saying it’s a [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)  issue, but to doesn’t seem that simple. I would recommend using this cleaned up code instead:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");
$result = mysqli_query($con , "select * from members where id=$id");

echo <<<EOT
<form action = "updatemem.php" method = 'POST'>
<br><br><br><br>
<center>
<b>EDIT RECORD</b><br><br>
EOT;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>";
  echo "Lastname: <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$row[lastname]'><br/>";
  echo "Codename: <input type='password' name='codename' value='$row[codename]'><br/>";
  echo "Location: <input type='text' name='location' value='$row[location]'><br/>";
  echo "Rank: <input type='text' name='rank' value='$row[rank]'><br/>";
}

echo <<<EOT
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Record">
</center>
</form>
EOT;
```

The problem is you had a weird `HEREDOC` of this:

```
echo <<<_END;
```

Which makes no sense. The error is PHP basically coming to that line, not understanding what `<<<_END;` means, and dying.

Then on top of that you have that whole `while` statement:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Which is PHP code being placed right after unclosed HTML via an attempt at a `HEREDOC`. Followed by more HTML:

```
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Record">
</center>
</form>
```

And that stuff had no `echo` statements. It’s just floating in there as HTML.

Which all means you don’t really understand how HTML & PHP mix together. Which is fair, but you need to understand that to avoid simple issues like this.

For my taste, this is how I would format this code. I would simply make it all PHP and use concatenation to connect all of the echo items & place them neatly on separate lines to make it easier to read.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");
$result = mysqli_query($con , "select * from members where id=$id");

echo '<form action = "updatemem.php" method="POST">'
   . '<br><br><br><br>'
   . '<center>'
   . '<b>EDIT RECORD</b><br><br>'
   ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>"
     . "Lastname: <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$row[lastname]'><br/>"
     . "Codename: <input type='password' name='codename' value='$row[codename]'><br/>"
     . "Location: <input type='text' name='location' value='$row[location]'><br/>"
     . "Rank: <input type='text' name='rank' value='$row[rank]'><br/>"
     ;
}

echo '<br>'
   . '<input type="submit" value="Edit Record">'
   . '</center>'
   . '</form>'
   ;
```

Comment: That will still show error because you are not closing the `HEREDOC`

Comment: this works! thankyou :) Although I don't know what is it for.

Comment: I didn't know you were editing -_- `pingboo23`, Accept it as answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: yes. but I found @ShankarDamodaran 's answer easier.

Comment: @pingboo23, Jake gave you more details than mine , but i just avoided the `HEREDOC`. You should accept his answer. I just gave you an alternative answer.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Oh. I just accept what I'll use to fix this error.  Sorry, I'll just accept his answer. I'm just a beginner in php, I don't understand `HEREDOC` , that's why I found your answer much easier than his :)

Comment: @JakeGould this is not my code by the way. I don't recognize this as mine in the first place. It's my professor's code, I was just trying to run it in my pc. But I'm getting error that's why I asked here. lol

Comment: Smart answer, your idea just helped me now. The problem isn't with HEREDOC itself, it is with how the code was written.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your **`HEREDOC`** missing end limiter.

This is a no **`HEREDOC`** Solution

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");
$result = mysqli_query($con , "select * from members where id=$id");

?>

<form action = "updatemem.php" method = 'POST'>
<br><br><br><br>

<center>

<b>EDIT RECORD</b><br><br>
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>";
    echo "Lastname: <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$row[lastname]'><br/>";
    echo "Codename: <input type='password' name='codename' value='$row[codename]'><br/>";
    echo "Location: <input type='text' name='location' value='$row[location]'><br/>";
    echo "Rank: <input type='text' name='rank' value='$row[rank]'><br/>";
}
?>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Record">
</center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `END` to end the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

You also seem to be *misusing* the heredoc; you can't mix PHP and HTML inside it. Your `while` loop cannot work, it will be output to the browser as a string. This really isn't a valid use for heredoc anyways; what you actually want is to simply switch out of PHP context with `?>`:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");
$result = mysqli_query($con , "select * from members where id=$id");

?>
<form action = "updatemem.php" method = 'POST'>
<br><br><br><br>

<center>

<b>EDIT RECORD</b><br><br>

<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>";
echo "Lastname: <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$row[lastname]'><br/>";
echo "Codename: <input type='password' name='codename' value='$row[codename]'><br/>";
echo "Location: <input type='text' name='location' value='$row[location]'><br/>";
echo "Rank: <input type='text' name='rank' value='$row[rank]'><br/>";
}

?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Record">
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: like `_END;` ? I already tried putting this code after `</form>` tag. But still, doesn't work.

Comment: @pingboo23 It doesn't really matter, because as I said, you're misusing the heredoc to begin with. You can't put executable code inside it, your `while` loop that reads the database results cannot work.

Comment: As I keep saying, the heredoc is immaterial, it really isn't a suitable tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual for heredoc syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Don't put a semicolon at the end of that line. Try

```
echo <<<_END
```

Also, you need to end the block like

```
_END;
```

Comment: I tried this, but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @pingboo23 the issues meager raises are likely the reason.